# Using CompletableFuture.runAsync() vs ForkJoinPool.execute()

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, completable-future, forkjoinpool

Without passing an `Executor` to `CompletableFuture.runAsync()`, the common `ForkJoinPool` is used. Instead, for a simple task (e.g., I do not need to chain different tasks) that I want to be executed asynchronously, I might just use `ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute()`.

Why should one be preferred over the other? E.g., does `runAsync()` have any substantial overhead with respect to `execute()`? Does the former have any specific advantages over the latter?

Comment: If all you want is a simple asynchronous task, I'd think that `ExecutorService.submit( Callable )` would be preferred.  Why mess with more than that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) Is not only used for asynchronous future objects, it has some additional advantages and features for tracking the `Future` task using [isDone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#isDone--), [isCancelled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#isCancelled--) and [isCompletedExceptionally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#isCompletedExceptionally--) etc..

> To simplify monitoring, debugging, and tracking, all generated asynchronous tasks are instances of the marker interface CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask.

Here is one scenario were i can explain difference between using `ForkJoinPool.execute` and `CompletableFuture.runAsync`

**ForkJoinPool.execute** While using `execute` method if any exception is thrown by `Runnable` task then execution will terminate abnormally, so  you need try catch to handle any unexpected exceptions

```
 ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(()->{
     throw new RuntimeException();
 });
```

**output :**

```
Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5" java.lang.RuntimeException
at JavaDemoTest/com.test.TestOne.lambda$2(TestOne.java:17)
```

**CompletableFuture.runAsync** But while using `CompletableFuture` you can have `exceptionally` to handle any unexpected exceptions

```
CompletableFuture<Void> complete = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        throw new RuntimeException();

    }).exceptionally(ex -> {
        System.out.println("Exception handled");
        return null;
    });
```

**Output :**

```
Exception handled
```

Answer (score 1):

ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute() returns void. You can't track or control the execition of the task.

ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit() returns ForkJoinTask which implements Future. You can track or cancel the task using synchronous interface like Future.isDone, Future.get(), or Future.cancel.

CompletableFuture.runAsync returns CompletableFuture. In addition to the synchronous interface, it has asynchronous interface which allows to trigger other CompletableFutures, e.g.

```
 CompletableFuture.runAsync(task).thenAccept(anothertask);
```